# Better way to show Description and image Captions

Tags: post-thumbnails

I am using this code to display "Featured Image" Captions/Descriptions, also i will show my div with Captions/Descriptions only if they exist. Because my PHP skills are not best  
My question is : ***Is there a better (Wordpressy way) for achieving this?*** 
Thank you.

```
<?php
$get_desc = esc_html(get_post(get_post_thumbnail_id())->post_content);
$get_caption = esc_html(get_post(get_post_thumbnail_id())->post_excerpt);
$merge = $get_caption . '<br/>' . $get_desc;
                the_post_thumbnail();

if(!empty( $get_caption ) && empty( $get_desc )){//If caption is not empty show the div
                echo '<div class="featured_caption">' . $get_caption . '</div>';                    
                }

else if(!empty( $get_desc ) && !empty( $get_caption )){ //If both caption and description are not empty show the div
                echo '<div class="featured_caption">' . $merge . '</div>';
                }

else if(empty( $get_caption ) && !empty( $get_desc )){//If description is not empty show the div
                echo '<div class="featured_caption">' .  $get_desc . '</div>';
                }
                ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing WordPress specific here, but you could make your code easier to read by removing the repeating parts.

```
if ( $id = get_post_thumbnail_id() )
{
    $post = get_post( $id );
    $data = array(
        $post->post_content,
        $post->post_excerpt
    );
    // remove empty elements from array
    $data = array_map( 'trim', $data );
    $data = array_filter( $data );
    // escape the elements
    $data = array_map( 'esc_html', $data );

    if ( ! empty ( $data ) )
        print '<div class="featured_caption">' . join( '<br />', $data ) . '</div>';
}
```

Comment: I knew that my code was a bit bulky that is why I have asked a question. Thank you @toscho i really appreciate your help..